# Mutating per group, then ungrouping

Tags: r, dplyr

*EDITED*

I have a data.frame that I want to group by certain columns (just `y` below), select distinct rows within each group (w.r.t. `y` and `z` below) and then add a new column that specifies the number of columns per group. Then ungroup to return to the data.frame, including the new column.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(10,10,10,20),z=c(100,100,101,200))

x y  z   
1 10 100 
2 10 100 
3 10 101 
4 20 200
```

I want to receive the data.frame:

```
x y  z   n
1 10 100 2
3 10 101 2
4 20 200 1
```

The first two rows have `n=2` because both have the same `y` but different values for `z`.

Comment: What is the name of the grouping variable(s)?

Comment: @sindri_baldur Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question again to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it in data.table as an alternative

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,.(n := .GPR ), y]
```

BUT I guess your desired result can be received by

```
df[,.(n := .GPR ), .(y,z)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, you can use the following with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% distinct(y,z,.keep_all=TRUE) %>% add_count(y)
```

However, the distinctiveness of `x` is questionable, as `distinct` may not always take the "correct" row. The help description for `distinct` write

> If there are multiple rows for a given combination of inputs, only the first row will be preserved. If omitted, will use all variables.

But here, it clearly took the last row.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `slice_head`

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>%
     group_by(y, z) %>% 
     mutate(n = n()) %>% 
     slice_head(n = 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   y, z [3]
#      x     y     z     n
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1     1    10   100     2
#2     3    10   101     1
#3     4    20   200     1
```